# Bash throws error, line 8: $1: unbound variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am trying to learn how to use getopts so that I can have scripts with parsed input (although I think getopts could be better). I am trying to just write a simple script to return partition usage percentages. The problem is that one of my bash functions does not seem to like that I reference `$1` as an variable within the function. The reason I reference `$1` is because the `get_percent` function can be passed a mount point as an optional argument to display instead of all of the mount points.

#### The script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

get_percent(){
    if [ -n "$1" ] 
    then
        df -h $1 | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1,"\t",$5 }'
    else
        df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1,"\t",$5 }'
    fi
}

usage(){
    echo "script usage: $(basename $0) [-h] [-p] [-m mount_point]" >&2
}

# If the user doesn't supply any arguments, we run the script as normal
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
    get_percent
    exit 0
fi
# ...
```

#### The Output

```
$ bash thing.sh
thing.sh: line 8: $1: unbound variable

$ bash -x thing.sh
+ set -e
+ set -u
+ set -o pipefail
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ get_percent
thing.sh: line 8: $1: unbound variable
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `getopts`, does it? Your script exits due to `-u` before calling `getopts`.

Comment: @ikkachu no I guess it doesn't. But I'm not sure I can change the title now.

Comment: There should be that small "edit" text under the post, just beneath the tags in a question

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`set -u` will abort exactly as you describe if you reference a variable which has not been set.  You are invoking your script with no arguments, so `get_percent` is being invoked with no arguments, causing `$1` to be unset.

Either check for this before invoking your function, or use default expansions (`${1:-default}` will expand to `default` if not already set to something else).

Comment: In particular, one could use `[ -n "${1-}" ]` (that is, with an empty default value) to see if the parameter is set and non-empty; or `[ "${1+x}" = x ]` to see if it's set, even if empty.

Comment: I still get unbound variable error despite using `if [[ -n ${1-default} ]]`

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat I was still getting `unbound variable` as well until I used `:-` instead of `-`. So, for me at least, the `${1:-default}` no loner raised the error.

Comment: As a side note, if you are trying to access an array element with an index out of range, you get the same error (with syntax `${my_array[$index]}`).

Answer (score 25):

This is the effect of `set -u`.

You could check `$#` inside the function and avoid referencing `$1` if it is not set.

With `$#` you can access the number of parameters. In global context it is the number of parameters to the script, in a function it is the number of parameters to the function.

In the context of the question, it is

```
if [ $# -ge 1 ] && [ -n "$1" ]
then
    df -h $1 | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1,"\t",$5 }'
else
    df -h | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1,"\t",$5 }'
fi
```

Note that you have to use `[ $# -ge 1 ] && [ -n "$1" ]` and not `[ $# -ge 1 -a -n "$1" ]`, because that would first evaluate `$1` and then check `$#`.

Answer (score 10):

Other answers have mentioned that this is the effect of `set -u`. None of the other answers have mentioned that `set -u` can be reversed with `set +u`:

```bash
$ echo $VAR  # nothing echoed below as VAR is unset:

$ set -u
$ echo $VAR
bash: VAR: unbound variable
$ set +u
$ echo $VAR  # nothing echoed below as VAR is unset:
```

Answer (score 8):

With "set -u" in the script any reference to an unset variable will cause an error, especially testing if it has a value, which is what the script is doing.

The following function will test for unset variable without tripping the set -u:

```
if:IsSet() {
  [[ ${!1-x} == x ]] && return 1 || return 0
}
```

Using it:

`if:IsSet someVariableName || echo "someVariableName is not set"`

As for the actual function, test whether an argument was passed in, not whether it is empty. This will avoid the unset variable issue without you taking any special steps, like testing whether the variable has a value.

```
get_percent(){
    if [ ${#1} -eq 0 ]
```

BTW: Colon in a function name is just a character. It is valid in a function name in Bash, as are %, }, {, [, and a bunch of others :-)

Comment: This does not work if `someVariableName` happens to be set to 'x'.  You could fix it by using `[[ ${!1-x} == x ]] && [[ ${!1-y} == y ]] && return 1; return 0` in your `if:IsSet` function.

Comment: as @ilkkachu mentioned in another comment, you would be better off using `[ "${!1+x}" = "x" ]`. This bash parameter expansion will expand to x if and only if the name/symbol provided by !1 is set (that is, null (empty string) or any string of positive length).

Answer (score 6):

Since this is `bash` you can sidestep the check for `$1` being set and just use `"$@"` (`$1` is the first parameter, `$@` is all of them; when double-quoted, it disappears completely if it has no values, which avoids it being caught by `set -u`):

```
get_percent() {
    df -h "$@" | awk 'NR>1 { printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $5 }'
}
```

I've also tweaked the rest of the line slightly so that you don't get {space}{tab}{space} between the two values you output but insead you get just a {tab}. If you really want the two invisible spaces then change the `awk` to use `printf "%s \t %s\n", $1, $5`.

Comment: I will have to look into this. I'm not familiar with that variable type. Thanks

Comment: @TimothyPulliam I've added a short explanation of `$@` for you